# Strapi database empties if Render server goes down

Tags: database, deployment, render, strapi

I have a Strapi backend deployed on Render. I had no issue until yesterday, when the Render server went down for a few minutes. It looks like it shouldn't be a big problem because when the server started working again Strapi was also reactivated.

The thing is, that all the database was empty after this and the asigned public roles were deactivated. That is to say, Strapi was in the same situation as if it was deployed right after creating the project at the beginning.

Does anyone know how to prevent this in some other occasions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because Strapi has - by default - in `config/database.ts` (or .js) something like:

```
        filename: path.join(
          __dirname,
          '..',
          '..',
          env('DATABASE_FILENAME', '.tmp/data.db')
        ),
```

That means database filename is inside your repo that is cloned and cleaned up. You have to modify your config similarly to https://github.com/render-examples/strapi-sqlite/blob/master/config/database.js.